# Let me view the deleted answers to my own questions

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers

On a few occasions, some of the answers to my questions were deleted after they were posted, leaving me with no way to access them. Some of the deleted answers were actually useful to me,  so I'm not happy to see them go. Can we have a way for Stack Overflow users to view the deleted answers that were posted on their own questions, even if they are below the reputation threshold for viewing deleted questions?

[There's already a feature that allows users to view deleted questions and answers that they have posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted), although it appears that it still doesn't allow users to view answers that were given to their own question. I'm still looking forward to seeing the now-deleted answers that have been posted on my own questions.

Comment: Didn't you ask that already today?

Comment: He did, but it was framed differently.  Hopefully it works out better this time.

Comment: I'm not sure what to think...  my first thought was if the answer actually had value, it wouldn't have been deleted.  But on the other hand, what's the harm.  And it would be consistent with other features which gives the OP almost mod-like privileges on their own posts for some functions like editing.

Comment: I think this would cause confusion with new users. Why not combine "view deleted answers on your own questions" with the existing "view close and reopen votes on your own questions" privilege?

Comment: @animuson: How are those two things related?

Comment: @Robert They don't necessarily need to be related. I'm just saying that a 1 rep user shouldn't be seeing deleted answers. That was just the most relevant privilege I thought of, and it seems like a good threshold to apply to this situation as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Last paragraph pretty clearly explains the difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems like a reasonable request.

The only major con here is extra noise on the post for the OP, especially one that attracts a lot of poor quality answers, but [animuson's suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/141525/animuson) to make this a privilege would help limit the excess noise to users who are experienced enough to deal with it.  You could even further hide the deleted answers until the OP clicks a button to unhide deleted answers, although since deleted answers are normally buried under the undeleted answers for 10K users, that might be enough.

Answer (score 7):

I strongly am in favor of this feature.  I asked [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1883518/if-a-subseteq-c-then-ab-cap-c-ab-cap-c), and there were at least two answers which had a flaw; since the answer author didn't want to get downvoted when I pointed out the flaw, they removed their answers; however, they had at least 60% of the correct argument, and would help me get my question answered.  While I was reading the answer to see how much more of the (correct) argument I could glean from the incorrect answer, both users deleted their answers.  What's worse, whereas an edit takes a click to "Reload" the new version, these deleted answers were removed right from my screen, while I was in the middle of a sentence.

Seeing a deleted answer is better than no answer at all.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very good proposal but I'll say this shouldn't be granted to **ALL** users. It should be added to an existing Privilege. Like

[Remove new user restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) at 10 reputation

or

[View Close Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) at 500 reputation

or preferrably,

[Established User](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) at 1k reputation

This will ensure that only trusted users have access to this privilege