# What does it take to get a feature request implemented?

Tags: support, feature-request-process

[Can I view the deleted answers to my own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203131/) is a feature request on Meta.SE that has many upvotes.

This feature is quite important to me: important enough for me to spend the time to program it in myself.

Is it possible for me to request to be allowed to do so?

Comment: The thing you can do is put a bounty on it, edit stuff on it etc. to bring more attention to it. And there are features with far more upvotes that don't get implemented. That said, you shouldn't have been directing people to this question in that answer of yours; instead, explain why this feature is useful. Most people wouldn't want to see deleted posts on their question.

Comment: I understand I won't be able to get enough attention to this feature to get it implemented.  My question was, whether I may implement it myself.

Comment: No, you can't implement it yourself.

Comment: The feature you linked to exists for users that have the [Access To Moderator Tools](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege.

Comment: see [Listen to Your Community, But Don't Let Them Tell You What to Do](https://blog.codinghorror.com/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What does it take to get a feature request implemented?

First, you need to convince Stack Exchange that the feature is actually something that should be done.

Being popular is not enough - we are aware that Meta users are not, in fact, representative of all of the users and that sometimes, something that looks like a good idea at first blush is, in fact, a really bad one.

Now, some requests are all to do with the client side - things that user style sheets and user scripts can handle - and there are a bunch of those around (take a look at [stackapps](http://stackapps.com)). These are the kinds of features that you can implement yourself.

As for other features - we have written and open sourced a bunch of libraries that we use in our codebase. If you want to work on features of those - they are listed on [stackexchange.github.io](https://stackexchange.github.io/).

The Stack Exchange codebase itself, outside of the OSS we publish, is closed source.

This means:

> Is it possible for me to request to be allowed to do so?

Only if you get [hired as a developer by Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here#positions).

Comment: `Being popular is not enough`-- so what process (at least approximately) do you use to decide what to implement?

Comment: The community team will discuss ideas that have merit - some of these require extensive thinking and planning. Once planned they will ask the Q&A developers - sometimes an idea is just not feasible technically and will not happen.

Comment: I will add - 16 upvotes for a feature request is not what I would call [popular](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request?sort=votes).

Comment: I stated that in comments of the original post:   
 
`I understand I won't be able to get enough attention to this feature to get it implemented.`

I just wanted to know what sort of changes I can feasibly aim for in SE.

Comment: Well, I hope you have a better idea now :)

Comment: If you want an idea of what's feasible to get implemented, have a browse through [previously implemented feature requests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+status-completed).

Comment: @AlE. I guess I meant more of, have an idea which of my ideas for improvements are *not* feasible, :D